# verifying detached signature with BC

Tags: java, digital-signature, bouncycastle

How can I verify a detached signature (CMS/pkcs #7 signature) using the BouncyCastle provider in Java?

Currently, my code below throws an exception with the message `message-digest attribute value does not match calculated value`

```
Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());

File f = new File(filename);
byte[] buffer = new byte[(int)f.length()];
DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(f));
in.readFully(buffer);
in.close();

CMSSignedData signature = new CMSSignedData(buffer);
SignerInformation signer = (SignerInformation) signature.getSignerInfos().getSigners().iterator().next();
CertStore cs = signature.getCertificatesAndCRLs("Collection", "BC");
Iterator iter = cs.getCertificates(signer.getSID()).iterator();
X509Certificate certificate = (X509Certificate) iter.next();

CMSProcessable sc = signature.getSignedContent();

signer.verify(certificate, "BC");
```

Comment: Have you tested the code found here: http://bouncy-castle.1462172.n4.nabble.com/How-to-verify-detached-PKCS7-signature-with-Stream-content-data-td1464668.html ? Currently, there is no particular spot where you actually seem to take the detached data into account.

Comment: I solved this issue you can find answer [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8590426/s-mime-verification-with-x509-certificate/20649242#20649242

Answer (score 9):

You can verify detached signature by the following code :

```
public static boolean verif_Detached(String signed_file_name,String original_file_name) throws IOException, CMSException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchProviderException, CertStoreException, CertificateExpiredException, CertificateNotYetValidException{

    boolean result= false;
    Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider()); 

    File f = new File(signed_file_name);
    byte[] Sig_Bytes = new byte[(int)f.length()];
    DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(f));
    in.readFully(Sig_Bytes);
    in.close();

    File fi = new File(original_file_name);
    byte[] Data_Bytes = new byte[(int)fi.length()];
    DataInputStream input = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(fi));
    input.readFully(Data_Bytes);
    input.close();

    try{
        CMSSignedData cms = new CMSSignedData(new CMSProcessableByteArray(Data_Bytes), Sig_Bytes); 
        CertStore certStore = cms.getCertificatesAndCRLs("Collection", "BC"); 
        SignerInformationStore signers = cms.getSignerInfos(); 
        Collection c = signers.getSigners(); 
        Iterator it = c.iterator(); 
        while (it.hasNext()) { 
            SignerInformation signer = (SignerInformation) it.next(); 
            Collection certCollection = certStore.getCertificates(signer.getSID()); 
            Iterator certIt = certCollection.iterator(); 
            X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate) certIt.next();
            cert_signer=cert;
            result=signer.verify(cert, "BC");
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        result=false;
    }
    return result; 
}
```

Comment: Where CMSSignedData class comes from?

Comment: @cgajardo org.bouncycastle.cms.CMSSignedData

Answer (score 1):

the key for verify detached pKCS7 is use of CMSTypedStream ,like code below:

```
public void verifySign(byte[] signedData,byte[]bPlainText) throws Exception {
    InputStream is  = new ByteArrayInputStream(bPlainText);             
    CMSSignedDataParser sp = new CMSSignedDataParser(new CMSTypedStream (is),signedData);
    CMSTypedStream signedContent = sp.getSignedContent();           
    signedContent.drain();
    //CMSSignedData s = new CMSSignedData(signedData); 
    Store certStore = sp.getCertificates(); 

    SignerInformationStore signers = sp.getSignerInfos(); 
    Collection c = signers.getSigners();
    Iterator it = c.iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) 
    { 
        SignerInformation signer = (SignerInformation)it.next(); 
        Collection certCollection = certStore.getMatches(signer.getSID()); 
        Iterator certIt = certCollection.iterator(); 
        X509CertificateHolder certHolder = (X509CertificateHolder)certIt.next(); 
        if ( !signer.verify(new JcaSimpleSignerInfoVerifierBuilder().setProvider("BC").build(certHolder))) 
        { 
            throw new DENException("Verification FAILED! "); 
        } 
        else
        {
            logger.debug("verify success" );
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: you can verify detached signature by this code :  CMSSignedData cms = new CMSSignedData(new CMSProcessableByteArray(Data_Bytes), Sig_Bytes);

Answer (score 1):

You can find the answer to this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8590426/s-mime-verification-with-x509-certificate/20649242#20649242). This happening because how bouncy castle/open ssl treats the S/MIME message when S/MIME headers are not present.Solution is to add S/MIME headers to the message before signimg