# Correct way to sign and verify signature using bouncycastle

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, digital-signature, bouncycastle

I am using `bcmail-jdk16-1.46.jar` and `bcprov-jdk16-1.46.jar` **(Bouncycastle libraries)** to sign a `string` and then verify the `signature`.

**This is my `code` to sign a `string`:**

```
package my.package;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.security.Key;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.PrivateKey;
import java.security.Security;
import java.security.Signature;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.bouncycastle.cert.jcajce.JcaCertStore;
import org.bouncycastle.cms.CMSProcessableByteArray;
import org.bouncycastle.cms.CMSSignedData;
import org.bouncycastle.cms.CMSSignedDataGenerator;
import org.bouncycastle.cms.CMSTypedData;
import org.bouncycastle.cms.jcajce.JcaSignerInfoGeneratorBuilder;
import org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider;
import org.bouncycastle.operator.ContentSigner;
import org.bouncycastle.operator.jcajce.JcaContentSignerBuilder;
import org.bouncycastle.operator.jcajce.JcaDigestCalculatorProviderBuilder;
import org.bouncycastle.util.Store;

import sun.misc.BASE64Encoder;

public class SignMessage {

    static final String KEYSTORE_FILE = "keys/certificates.p12";
    static final String KEYSTORE_INSTANCE = "PKCS12";
    static final String KEYSTORE_PWD = "test";
    static final String KEYSTORE_ALIAS = "Key1";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        String text = "This is a message";

        Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());

        KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance(KEYSTORE_INSTANCE);
        ks.load(new FileInputStream(KEYSTORE_FILE), KEYSTORE_PWD.toCharArray());
        Key key = ks.getKey(KEYSTORE_ALIAS, KEYSTORE_PWD.toCharArray());

        //Sign
        PrivateKey privKey = (PrivateKey) key;
        Signature signature = Signature.getInstance("SHA1WithRSA", "BC");
        signature.initSign(privKey);
        signature.update(text.getBytes());

        //Build CMS
        X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate) ks.getCertificate(KEYSTORE_ALIAS);
        List certList = new ArrayList();
        CMSTypedData msg = new CMSProcessableByteArray(signature.sign());
        certList.add(cert);
        Store certs = new JcaCertStore(certList);
        CMSSignedDataGenerator gen = new CMSSignedDataGenerator();
        ContentSigner sha1Signer = new JcaContentSignerBuilder("SHA1withRSA").setProvider("BC").build(privKey);
        gen.addSignerInfoGenerator(new JcaSignerInfoGeneratorBuilder(new JcaDigestCalculatorProviderBuilder().setProvider("BC").build()).build(sha1Signer, cert));
        gen.addCertificates(certs);
        CMSSignedData sigData = gen.generate(msg, false);

        BASE64Encoder encoder = new BASE64Encoder();

        String signedContent = encoder.encode((byte[]) sigData.getSignedContent().getContent());
        System.out.println("Signed content: " + signedContent + "\n");

        String envelopedData = encoder.encode(sigData.getEncoded());
        System.out.println("Enveloped data: " + envelopedData);
    }
}
```

**Now, the `EnvelopedData` output will be used in the process to `verify` the `signature`:**

```
package my.package;

import java.security.Security;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Iterator;

import org.bouncycastle.cert.X509CertificateHolder;
import org.bouncycastle.cert.jcajce.JcaX509CertificateConverter;
import org.bouncycastle.cms.CMSSignedData;
import org.bouncycastle.cms.SignerInformation;
import org.bouncycastle.cms.SignerInformationStore;
import org.bouncycastle.cms.jcajce.JcaSimpleSignerInfoVerifierBuilder;
import org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider;
import org.bouncycastle.util.Store;
import org.bouncycastle.util.encoders.Base64;

public class VerifySignature {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        String envelopedData = "MIAGCSqGSIb3DQEHAqCAMIACAQExCzAJBgUrDgMCGgUAMIAGCSqGSIb3DQEHAQAAoIAwggLQMIIC" + 
                               "OQIEQ479uzANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUFADCBrjEmMCQGCSqGSIb3DQEJARYXcm9zZXR0YW5ldEBtZW5k" + 
                               "ZWxzb24uZGUxCzAJBgNVBAYTAkRFMQ8wDQYDVQQIEwZCZXJsaW4xDzANBgNVBAcTBkJlcmxpbjEi" +
                               "MCAGA1UEChMZbWVuZGVsc29uLWUtY29tbWVyY2UgR21iSDEiMCAGA1UECxMZbWVuZGVsc29uLWUt" + 
                               "Y29tbWVyY2UgR21iSDENMAsGA1UEAxMEbWVuZDAeFw0wNTEyMDExMzQyMTlaFw0xOTA4MTAxMzQy" + 
                               "MTlaMIGuMSYwJAYJKoZIhvcNAQkBFhdyb3NldHRhbmV0QG1lbmRlbHNvbi5kZTELMAkGA1UEBhMC" + 
                               "REUxDzANBgNVBAgTBkJlcmxpbjEPMA0GA1UEBxMGQmVybGluMSIwIAYDVQQKExltZW5kZWxzb24t" + 
                               "ZS1jb21tZXJjZSBHbWJIMSIwIAYDVQQLExltZW5kZWxzb24tZS1jb21tZXJjZSBHbWJIMQ0wCwYD" + 
                               "VQQDEwRtZW5kMIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQC+X1g6JvbdwJI6mQMNT41GcycH" + 
                               "UbwCFWKJ4qHDaHffz3n4h+uQJJoQvc8yLTCfnl109GB0yL2Y5YQtTohOS9IwyyMWBhh77WJtCN8r" + 
                               "dOfD2DW17877te+NlpugRvg6eOH6np9Vn3RZODVxxTyyJ8pI8VMnn13YeyMMw7VVaEO5hQIDAQAB" + 
                               "MA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBBQUAA4GBALwOIc/rWMAANdEh/GgO/DSkVMwxM5UBr3TkYbLU/5jg0Lwj3Y++" + 
                               "KhumYSrxnYewSLqK+JXA4Os9NJ+b3eZRZnnYQ9eKeUZgdE/QP9XE04y8WL6ZHLB4sDnmsgVaTU+p" + 
                               "0lFyH0Te9NyPBG0J88109CXKdXCTSN5gq0S1CfYn0staAAAxggG9MIIBuQIBATCBtzCBrjEmMCQG" + 
                               "CSqGSIb3DQEJARYXcm9zZXR0YW5ldEBtZW5kZWxzb24uZGUxCzAJBgNVBAYTAkRFMQ8wDQYDVQQI" + 
                               "EwZCZXJsaW4xDzANBgNVBAcTBkJlcmxpbjEiMCAGA1UEChMZbWVuZGVsc29uLWUtY29tbWVyY2Ug" + 
                               "R21iSDEiMCAGA1UECxMZbWVuZGVsc29uLWUtY29tbWVyY2UgR21iSDENMAsGA1UEAxMEbWVuZAIE" + 
                               "Q479uzAJBgUrDgMCGgUAoF0wGAYJKoZIhvcNAQkDMQsGCSqGSIb3DQEHATAcBgkqhkiG9w0BCQUx" + 
                               "DxcNMTMwNTIxMDE1MDUzWjAjBgkqhkiG9w0BCQQxFgQU8mE6gw6iudxLUc9379lWK0lUSWcwDQYJ" + 
                               "KoZIhvcNAQEBBQAEgYB5mVhqJu1iX9nUqfqk7hTYJb1lR/hQiCaxruEuInkuVTglYuyzivZjAR54" + 
                               "zx7Cfm5lkcRyyxQ35ztqoq/V5JzBa+dYkisKcHGptJX3CbmmDIa1s65mEye4eLS4MTBvXCNCUTb9" + 
                               "STYSWvr4VPenN80mbpqSS6JpVxjM0gF3QTAhHwAAAAAAAA==";

        Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());

        CMSSignedData cms = new CMSSignedData(Base64.decode(envelopedData.getBytes()));
        Store store = cms.getCertificates(); 
        SignerInformationStore signers = cms.getSignerInfos(); 
        Collection c = signers.getSigners(); 
        Iterator it = c.iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) { 
            SignerInformation signer = (SignerInformation) it.next(); 
            Collection certCollection = store.getMatches(signer.getSID()); 
            Iterator certIt = certCollection.iterator();
            X509CertificateHolder certHolder = (X509CertificateHolder) certIt.next();
            X509Certificate cert = new JcaX509CertificateConverter().setProvider("BC").getCertificate(certHolder);
            if (signer.verify(new JcaSimpleSignerInfoVerifierBuilder().setProvider("BC").build(cert))) {
                System.out.println("verified");
            }
        }

    }

}
```

**Everything works fine until `signer.verify(..)` due to the following `Exception`:**

```
Exception in thread "main" org.bouncycastle.cms.CMSSignerDigestMismatchException: message-digest attribute value does not match calculated value
    at org.bouncycastle.cms.SignerInformation.doVerify(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.cms.SignerInformation.verify(Unknown Source)
    at my.package.VerifySignature.main(VerifySignature.java:64)
```

Can someone please give me a hint of what could be happening?

---

***PS***. If someone wants to test above `code` you will need the test `certificate` file that I am using to replicate this, just `download` it from here:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/zs4jo1a86v8qamw/certificates.p12?dl=0

Comment: what release of JDK are you using? versions above 1.7.4 have security issues when working with this kind of functionality. If you haven't tried already change your Jdk for a 1.7.2.

Comment: @MarceloTataje I am using `JDK` **1.7.0** version.

Comment: Any idea how to retrieve the message after the sign verification?

Comment: @Raj don't remember at all but I'll recommend you to download this implementation from http://as2.mendelson-e-c.com/ (which is "like" a Java client that sends requests and receive responses and in that process it will encrypt, decrypt, sign, verify a message). In order to see the code try using a Java decompiler to check the sources of the generated jar after installation, it really helps as a reference.

Comment: @Oscar Jara I know it is late to ask now but do you happen to have the java code used to generate the certificate file (certificates.p12)?

Comment: @Sebi There's no Java code for that, you just need an `openssl` command, I don't remember it (to be honest) but I can try to find it and keep you posted.

Comment: Hey I'm facing the same issue... Have u resolved this problem ??- @OscarJara

Comment: @Mallikarjun Yes, I solved that, you should read the post marked as the answer carefully and do some research around that, then you will find out

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The

```
gen.generate(msg, false)
```

means the signed data is not encapsulated in the signature. This is fine if you want to create a detached signature, but it does mean that when you go to verify the SignedData you have to use the CMSSignedData constructor that takes a copy of the data as well - in this case the code is using the single argument constructor which has to assume the signed data was encapsulated (so for this case will be empty), with the result that the attempt at verification is failing.

Answer (score 15):

There are two kinds of ***CMSSignedData*** object generated using ***CMSSignedDataGenerator*** They are generated by the following way:

The one below generates a CMSSignedData object carrying a detached CMS signature

```
gen.generate(cmsdata);
```

The code below creates a CMSSignedData carrying a detached CMS signature, having the data encapsulated

```
gen.generate(cmsdata, true);
```

So verifying them requires 2 approaches

Approach No.1 to verify detached signature with encapsulated data

```
//sig is the Signature object
CMSSignedData signedData = new CMSSignedData(Base64.decode(sig.getBytes()));
```

Approach No.2 to verify detached signature without encapsulated data, just the detached signature

```
//Create a CMSProcessable object, specify any encoding, I have used mine 
CMSProcessable signedContent = new CMSProcessableByteArray(content.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"));
//Create a InputStream object
InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(Base64.decode(sig.getBytes()));
//Pass them both to CMSSignedData constructor
CMSSignedData signedData = new CMSSignedData(signedContent, is);
```

Rest of the code for verification remains the same

```
Store store = signedData.getCertificates(); 
SignerInformationStore signers = signedData.getSignerInfos(); 

Collection c = signers.getSigners(); 
Iterator it = c.iterator(); 

while (it.hasNext()) { 
    SignerInformation signer = (SignerInformation)it.next(); 

    Collection certCollection = store.getMatches(signer.getSID()); 
    Iterator certIt = certCollection.iterator(); 

    X509CertificateHolder certHolder = (X509CertificateHolder)certIt.next(); 
    X509Certificate cert = new JcaX509CertificateConverter().setProvider("BC").getCertificate(certHolder); 

    if (signer.verify(new JcaSimpleSignerInfoVerifierBuilder().setProvider("BC").build(cert))) {
        ret = true; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

If we use signature.sign() as in the OP's answer, we won't be able to retrieve the original message, because its only the signature.

You should just input the original text bytes rather than the signed content. Basically, ignore this part:

```
//Sign
PrivateKey privKey = (PrivateKey) key;
Signature signature = Signature.getInstance("SHA1WithRSA", "BC");
signature.initSign(privKey);
signature.update(text.getBytes());
```

and just input as:

```
CMSTypedData msg = new CMSProcessableByteArray(text.getBytes());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find answer at this link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8590426/s-mime-verification-with-x509-certificate/20649242#20649242) You need to just add some headers to message or just add one blank line before message then sign the message then it will work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Got it working for detached signature :D

```
package signature;

import java.security.Provider;
import java.security.Security;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Iterator;
import org.bouncycastle.cert.X509CertificateHolder;
import org.bouncycastle.cert.jcajce.JcaX509CertificateConverter;
import org.bouncycastle.cms.CMSProcessable;
import org.bouncycastle.cms.CMSProcessableByteArray;
import org.bouncycastle.cms.CMSSignedData;
import org.bouncycastle.cms.SignerInformation;
import org.bouncycastle.cms.SignerInformationStore;
import org.bouncycastle.cms.jcajce.JcaSimpleSignerInfoVerifierBuilder;
import org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider;
import org.bouncycastle.util.Store;
import org.bouncycastle.util.encoders.Base64;


public class VerifySignature {

    static final String DIGEST_SHA1 = "SHA1withRSA";
    static final String BC_PROVIDER = "BC";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        String envelopedData = "MIAGCSqGSIb3DQEHAqCAMIACAQExCzAJBgUrDgMCGgUAMIAGCSqGSIb3DQEHAQAAoIAwggLQMIIC" + 
                               "OQIEQ479uzANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUFADCBrjEmMCQGCSqGSIb3DQEJARYXcm9zZXR0YW5ldEBtZW5k" + 
                               "ZWxzb24uZGUxCzAJBgNVBAYTAkRFMQ8wDQYDVQQIEwZCZXJsaW4xDzANBgNVBAcTBkJlcmxpbjEi" +
                               "MCAGA1UEChMZbWVuZGVsc29uLWUtY29tbWVyY2UgR21iSDEiMCAGA1UECxMZbWVuZGVsc29uLWUt" + 
                               "Y29tbWVyY2UgR21iSDENMAsGA1UEAxMEbWVuZDAeFw0wNTEyMDExMzQyMTlaFw0xOTA4MTAxMzQy" + 
                               "MTlaMIGuMSYwJAYJKoZIhvcNAQkBFhdyb3NldHRhbmV0QG1lbmRlbHNvbi5kZTELMAkGA1UEBhMC" + 
                               "REUxDzANBgNVBAgTBkJlcmxpbjEPMA0GA1UEBxMGQmVybGluMSIwIAYDVQQKExltZW5kZWxzb24t" + 
                               "ZS1jb21tZXJjZSBHbWJIMSIwIAYDVQQLExltZW5kZWxzb24tZS1jb21tZXJjZSBHbWJIMQ0wCwYD" + 
                               "VQQDEwRtZW5kMIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQC+X1g6JvbdwJI6mQMNT41GcycH" + 
                               "UbwCFWKJ4qHDaHffz3n4h+uQJJoQvc8yLTCfnl109GB0yL2Y5YQtTohOS9IwyyMWBhh77WJtCN8r" + 
                               "dOfD2DW17877te+NlpugRvg6eOH6np9Vn3RZODVxxTyyJ8pI8VMnn13YeyMMw7VVaEO5hQIDAQAB" + 
                               "MA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBBQUAA4GBALwOIc/rWMAANdEh/GgO/DSkVMwxM5UBr3TkYbLU/5jg0Lwj3Y++" + 
                               "KhumYSrxnYewSLqK+JXA4Os9NJ+b3eZRZnnYQ9eKeUZgdE/QP9XE04y8WL6ZHLB4sDnmsgVaTU+p" + 
                               "0lFyH0Te9NyPBG0J88109CXKdXCTSN5gq0S1CfYn0staAAAxggG9MIIBuQIBATCBtzCBrjEmMCQG" + 
                               "CSqGSIb3DQEJARYXcm9zZXR0YW5ldEBtZW5kZWxzb24uZGUxCzAJBgNVBAYTAkRFMQ8wDQYDVQQI" + 
                               "EwZCZXJsaW4xDzANBgNVBAcTBkJlcmxpbjEiMCAGA1UEChMZbWVuZGVsc29uLWUtY29tbWVyY2Ug" + 
                               "R21iSDEiMCAGA1UECxMZbWVuZGVsc29uLWUtY29tbWVyY2UgR21iSDENMAsGA1UEAxMEbWVuZAIE" + 
                               "Q479uzAJBgUrDgMCGgUAoF0wGAYJKoZIhvcNAQkDMQsGCSqGSIb3DQEHATAcBgkqhkiG9w0BCQUx" + 
                               "DxcNMTMwNTIxMDE1MDUzWjAjBgkqhkiG9w0BCQQxFgQU8mE6gw6iudxLUc9379lWK0lUSWcwDQYJ" + 
                               "KoZIhvcNAQEBBQAEgYB5mVhqJu1iX9nUqfqk7hTYJb1lR/hQiCaxruEuInkuVTglYuyzivZjAR54" + 
                               "zx7Cfm5lkcRyyxQ35ztqoq/V5JzBa+dYkisKcHGptJX3CbmmDIa1s65mEye4eLS4MTBvXCNCUTb9" + 
                               "STYSWvr4VPenN80mbpqSS6JpVxjM0gF3QTAhHwAAAAAAAA==";
        String Sig_Bytes ="YduK22AlMLSXV3ajX5r/pX5OQ0xjj58uhGT9I9MvOrz912xNHo+9OiOKeMOD+Ys2/LUW3XaN6T+/"+
                "tuRM5bi4RK7yjaqaJCZWtr/O4I968BQGgt0cyNvK8u0Jagbr9MYk6G7nnejbRXYHyAOaunqD05lW"+
                "U/+g92i18dl0OMc50m4=";

        Provider provider = new BouncyCastleProvider();
        Security.addProvider(provider);
        CMSSignedData signedData = new CMSSignedData(Base64.decode(envelopedData.getBytes()));

        CMSProcessable cmsProcesableContent = new CMSProcessableByteArray(Base64.decode(Sig_Bytes.getBytes()));
        signedData = new CMSSignedData(cmsProcesableContent, Base64.decode(envelopedData.getBytes()));
        // Verify signature
        Store store = signedData.getCertificates(); 
        SignerInformationStore signers = signedData.getSignerInfos(); 
        Collection c = signers.getSigners(); 
        Iterator it = c.iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) { 
            SignerInformation signer = (SignerInformation) it.next(); 
            Collection certCollection = store.getMatches(signer.getSID()); 
            Iterator certIt = certCollection.iterator();
            X509CertificateHolder certHolder = (X509CertificateHolder) certIt.next();
            X509Certificate certFromSignedData = new JcaX509CertificateConverter().setProvider(BC_PROVIDER).getCertificate(certHolder);
            if (signer.verify(new JcaSimpleSignerInfoVerifierBuilder().setProvider(BC_PROVIDER).build(certFromSignedData))) {
                System.out.println("Signature verified");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Signature verification failed");
            }
        }
    }



}
```