# Adding Signing certificate as signed attributes in CMS

Tags: java, x509certificate, bouncycastle

Is this the way to add the signing certificate as signed attribute?

```
JcaSignerInfoGeneratorBuilder builder = new JcaSignerInfoGeneratorBuilder(new JcaDigestCalculatorProviderBuilder().setProvider("BC").build());
Attribute attr = new Attribute(CMSAttributes.messageDigest, new DERSet(new DEROctetString( this.digest(myCert.getEncoded()) )));// using SHA-512 for this.digest()
ASN1EncodableVector v = new ASN1EncodableVector();
v.add(attr);
builder.setSignedAttributeGenerator(new DefaultSignedAttributeTableGenerator(new AttributeTable(v)));
```

On verification

```
signerInformation.verify(new JcaSimpleSignerInfoVerifierBuilder().setProvider("BC").build(cert))
```

I got exception:

```
org.bouncycastle.cms.CMSSignerDigestMismatchException: message-digest attribute value does not match calculated value
```

For digest calculation of the attribute I use SHA-512, for signing SHA512withRSA.

Comment: Your question does not make sense. A `SignerInfo` *contains* the signature of the data with respect to one signer and *refers to* (does NOT contain) the signing cert. If `signedAttrs` is used, which is common but not universal, it must contain message-digest with the digest of the *data*, *and* content-type. See 5.3 of rfc5652. The signing cert(s), and its(their) chain(s), should be included in the `certificates` field (NOT `signerInfos`) *unless* the recipient(s) already has(have) it(them), see 5.1.  ...

Comment: ... You should never need to sign a certificate, it is already signed by the CA that issued it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16662408/correct-way-to-sign-and-verify-signature-using-bouncycastle has an answer reported to work for detached signature; it puts the certs (*and* signerinfo) into a `CMSSignedDataGenerator` which at least appear to match the RFC. I presume nondetached/embedded would be similar, but haven't tested either.

Comment: According to ETSI TS 101 733 v.1.8.1; One of ESS signing-certificate or ESS signing-certificate-v2 must be mandatory signed attributes.

Answer (score 3):

The signing certificate can be added as signed attribute using BouncyCastle as:

```
final X500Name issuerX500Name = new X509CertificateHolder(mycert.getEncoded()).getIssuer();
final GeneralName generalName = new GeneralName(issuerX500Name);
final GeneralNames generalNames = new GeneralNames(generalName);
final BigInteger serialNumber = mycert.getSerialNumber();
final IssuerSerial issuerSerial = new IssuerSerial(generalNames, serialNumber);

ESSCertIDv2 certid = new ESSCertIDv2(new AlgorithmIdentifier(new ASN1ObjectIdentifier("2.16.840.1.101.3.4.2.3")), this.digest(mycert.getEncoded()), issuerSerial);
SigningCertificateV2 sigcert = new SigningCertificateV2(certid);
final DERSet attrValues = new DERSet(sigcert);
Attribute attr = new Attribute(PKCSObjectIdentifiers.id_aa_signingCertificateV2, attrValues);
ASN1EncodableVector v = new ASN1EncodableVector();
v.add(attr);

JcaSignerInfoGeneratorBuilder builder = new JcaSignerInfoGeneratorBuilder(new JcaDigestCalculatorProviderBuilder().setProvider("BC").build());
builder.setSignedAttributeGenerator(new DefaultSignedAttributeTableGenerator(new AttributeTable(v)));
```