# Cms exception while verifying the signature

Tags: bouncycastle, verifyerror

I'm trying to use the `bouncycastle` for generating and verifying the signatures.the code used is

[Correct way to sign and verify signature using bouncycastle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16662408/correct-way-to-sign-and-verify-signature-using-boucycastle)

But I'm getting the exception

```
Org.bouncycastle.cms.CMSException.IOException reading content
Java.io.IOException : DER length more than 4 bytes.
```

Can anyone please help to resolve this exception?

Comment: It would be useful if you could post a code snippet

Comment: You can find the code used here

Comment: The exception occurs at the line where the signedData object is initialised with signed Content and signature the line is CMSSignedData signedData = new CMSSignedData(signedContent, is)

Comment: Firstly, did you read the entire question you linked to and understand the discussion of detached signatures? Secondly, there are at least 3 different code examples there, so to avoid confusion it will be better if you post the exact code that you have tried.