# How to verify JSON file (PKCS#7 detached signature in the .p7s file, CAdES-B compliant signature)

Tags: java, spring-boot, multipartform-data, x509certificate, verification

In my REST API I am getting multipart files with a request. I get a JSON file, and p7s file, which is a signature of that JSON file. I have the public certificate which was used to sign it.

I need to verify JSON file with jsonSig file.

Code I have written by now is:

```
public void getFiles(@RequestParam("json") MultipartFile json,
                                        @RequestParam("json-sig") MultipartFile jsonSig) throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyStoreException, CertificateException, InvalidKeyException, SignatureException {

    String certificate = CERTIFIFATE;
    CertificateFactory certificateFactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
    byte[] base64Bytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(certificate);
    X509Certificate x509Certificate = (X509Certificate) certificateFactory.generateCertificate(new ByteArrayInputStream(base64Bytes));

    Signature signature = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withRSA");
    signature.initVerify(x509Certificate.getPublicKey());
    signature.update(json.getBytes());
    InputStream bytessss = jsonSig.getInputStream();
    boolean isCorrect = signature.verify(jsonSig.getBytes());
```

I get an error in the last line:

> java.security.SignatureException: Signature length not correct: got
> 6793 but was expecting 256] with root cause

I probably need to extract just a certificate from jsonSig, but I have no clue how to do that.

Comment: A PKCS7/CMS signature -- and CAdES is basically just CMS with added constraints -- is per Doug Adams almost completely unlike the raw cryptographic signature your code would handle. If you can use bouncycastle see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17043569/pkcs7-verify-digital-signature-in-java?rq=1 (already suggested as Related) plus link there.

Comment: Thank you very much, it helped me to go into good direction but luckily that requirement was removed from my project and I couldn't test it and make it work.