# Verifying Detached Signature (Mdm-Signature) of iOS MDM messages

Tags: java, ios, mdm

I've read [verifying detached signature with BC](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8612959/4656824), but still I don't know how I can verify Mdm-Signature of MDM message from iOS device.

Apple's Mobile Device Management Protocol Reference document said as follows:

> If the value of the SignMessage field in the MDM payload is set to
>   true, each message coming from the device will carry an additional
>   HTTP header named Mdm-Signature. This header contains a BASE64-encoded
>   CMS Detached Signature of the message.

So I set the value of the SignMessage field to true. Then the device carried an header named Mdm-Signature. And I used the method provided by the article of the link above, verifySign(byte[] signedData, byte[]bPlainText) like below (I modified return type to boolean. It returns true if verification successed):

```
boolean verified = verifySign(Base64.decode(request.getHeader("Mdm-Signature")),
                   IOUtils.toString(request.getInputStream(), "utf-8").getBytes());
```

(The variable "request" above is the instance of HttpServletRequest class that is passed to doPut method of HttpServlet class.)

But the value of "verified" is **false**.

So what I wonder is **what paramter exactly I have to pass to the method verifySign()**.

See also followings:

> - The client includes an “Mdm-Signature:” header in the HTTP PUT    messages it sends to the server
> - This signature is a base-64 encoded, .DER format, SMIME signature
> - The content which is signed is not included in the signature, but    is instead the content of the PUT itself — the message being sent
>     to the MDM server
> - Finally, it’s signed using the private Identity key that was sent    to the device at MDM enrollment

These are from [this page](https://intrepidusgroup.com/insight/2012/02/ios-mdm-preventing-disassociation-dos-and-potemkin-devices/).
What I also wonder from these is **whether the server needs client public key to verify detached signature**. No need?